# Why use label in docker-compose.yml, can't environment do the job?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning docker now. I am trying to figure out what kind of problem [Docker label](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/) can solve.

I can understand why [use label in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label), e.g add build-related metadata, but I still don't get why [using it](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels-2) in docker-compose.yml? What is the difference between using labels vs [environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)? I assume there will be different use cases but I just can't figure it out.

Can someone give me some practical example?

Thanks

Comment: You mean why use it in docker-compose.yml other than for build related stuff?

Comment: yes that was my question

Comment: Maybe you want to add some info that you don't want to expose through env vars in your containers

Comment: You mean it will get a default name based on the service name?

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose.yml is used by docker-compose utility to build and run the services which you have defined in `docker-compose.yml`
While working with docker-compose we can use two thing

1. `docker-compose build` this will build the services which is defined under `docker-compose.yml` but in order to run this services it has to have a image which is with `docker-engine` if you do `docker image ls` you find the images which is built up with the `docker-compose` and inspect it there you find a `label` which defines the metadata of that particular image.
2. `docker-compose up` this will run the services which is built up in `docker-container build` now this running container has to have some metadata like `env` this is set with `enviroment` in `docker-compose.yml`

P.S. :- This is my first answer in stack overflow. If you didn't get just give a comment I will try to explain my best.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So you were saying label is used to build the image while env is used to run the container ?

Comment: Yes, but they both are use to provide metadata about the container nothing else. Like you can put enviroment vairable as "production" or "test" depending upon your enviroment you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to use `labels` in `docker-compose` is to flag your `containers` as part of *this* docker-compose suite of containers, as opposed to other purposes each docker `image` might get used for.

Here's an example docker-compose.yml that shares labels across two services:

```
x-common-labels: &common-labels
  my.project.environment: "my project"
  my.project.maintainer: "me@example.com"

services:
  s1:
    image: somebodyelse/someimage
    labels:
      <<: *common-labels
    # ...
  s2:
    build:
      context: .
    image: my/s2
    labels:
    <<: *common-labels
    # ...
```

Then you can do things like this to just kill this project's containers.

```
docker rm -f $(docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}" --filter "label=my.project.environment")
```

#### re: labels vs. environment variables

Labels are only available to the `docker` and `docker-compose` commands on your host.

Environment variables are also available at run-time *inside* the docker container.

Comment: Yes, I know. I can kill this project's containers with a simple `docker-compose down`.  I was just giving a quick example of setting and using labels at the container level, without modifying the images.

Answer (score 0):

LABEL can be utilized to embed as much metadata as possible about the Docker image, so to make it easier to work with.

Some main purposes of adding LABEL to a Docker image are:

- As a documentation.
  You can provide author, description, link to a usage instructions etc.
- For versioning.
  You can ensure that some new features even with the same `latest` tag will be applicable for certain versions, so might not broke some old existing features.
- Any other metadata for programmatic access.

This [page](http://label-schema.org/rc1) provides a guideline and the most common usages of Docker LABEL.